# How do I send and display Get Requests in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, .net-maui

I'm trying to implement a small app using .NET MAUI, but I keep getting errors at runtime

> System.Net.WebException: 'Unable to resolve host "reqres.in": No
> address associated with hostname'

Sometimes I receive the error sounding like:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

To display the response I used the ListView-control, and finally the CollectionView

I installed Newtonsoft.Json using Nuget Package Manager.

The code-behind file contains the following code:

```
private const string url = "https://reqres.in/api/users";
private HttpClient _Client = new HttpClient();
private ObservableCollection<User> userCollection;

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        
        base.OnAppearing();

        var httpResponse = await _Client.GetAsync(url);

        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Response responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            userCollection = new ObservableCollection<User>(responseData.Users);
            User_List.ItemsSource = userCollection;
        }
    }

public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("avatar")]
    public string AvatarURI { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return $"{FirstName} {LastName}"; }
    }
}

public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("page")]
    public int Page { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("per_page")]
    public int PerPage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("total")]
    public int Total { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("total_pages")]
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

The XAML file's content is:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="TabbedPageTest.TeamMembersPage"
         BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}">
  <StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Team Members"/>
    <CollectionView x:Name="User_List" HeightRequest="400" >
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding AvatarURI}" Text="{Binding FullName}" Detail="{Binding Email}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
    <Button Text="Back" Clicked="OnBackButtonClicked" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: This looks problematic to me: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())`. You should await the response and check if the response was a correct one (no 4xx nor 5xx http status codes in the response).

Comment: My guess about the error message you got is that the http server `regres.in` was offline or you had network problems (either connectivity or DNS). Actually that server seems online and that URL does work, so it is probably a temporal problem.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought of the server being offline, after implementing the same functionality in a Blazor app I was able to display the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use the ListView control instead of CollectionView, the app runs successfully and no errors are shown.

I mentioned that I used the ListView control, which I didn't test properly.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TabbedPageTest.TeamMembersPage"
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Team Members"/>
        <ListView x:Name="User_List" 
                  HeightRequest="400"
                  ItemSelected="OnListItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding AvatarURI}" Text="{Binding FullName}" Detail="{Binding Email}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button Text="Back" Clicked="OnBackButtonClicked" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: This "answer" concerns me. I am seriously considering downvoting it, because at best it is misleading. The question remains: did that change really fix it? or did/do you have a lurking issue in either timing-dependent code, or in writing reliable code to detect server problems? **Neither of the two error messages you got have anything to do with whether a ListView or CollectionView is used.** IMHO, Unless you also made other code changes not shown here, **expect the problem to crop up again,** at some inconvenient time, during future testing or deployment. Or in customer error reports.

Answer (score 1):

While this is old, here is a possible explanation for people searching for a similar issue.

I had the same issue so moved the httpResponse code into a new method GetData and called that after the InitializeComponent in mainPage. I think maybe OnAppearing could have timing issues. I changed my code and haven't had a problem.