# How to pass an API request

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, .net-maui

Using this documentation: https://newsdata.io/docs, I use an api in .NET MAUI, but the request does not work yet I have no error message and I followed step by step the instructions, when I do a refresh the loading remains continuous.
I added the api key where it was necessary then I tried with the Request Parameters.

```
public class NewsService
    {
        const string BASE_URL = "//APIKEY//=au,calanguage=fr,en";

        HttpClient client;

        public NewsService()
        {
            client = new();
        }
        public async Task<List<NewsDataModel>> GetRandomNewsAsync()
        {
            var page = new Random().Next(1, 1000);

            var url = $"{BASE_URL}&page={page}&page_size=10";

            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            var newsData = await GetNewsAsync(response);

            return newsData;    
        }
        private async Task<List<NewsDataModel>> GetNewsAsync(HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            List<NewsDataModel> newsData = new();

            if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                newsData = (await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<NewsResult>()).Data;
            }
            return newsData;
        }
```

```
public partial class NewsViewModel : BaseViewModel
   {
       NewsService newsService;

       public ObservableCollection<NewsDataModel> News { get; set; } = new();

       [ObservableProperty]
       bool isRefreshing;

       public NewsViewModel(NewsService newsService)
       {
           Title = "News";
           this.newsService = newsService;
       }

       [RelayCommand]
       async Task GetRandomNewsAsync()
       {
           if (IsBusy) 
           return;

           try
           {
               IsBusy = true;

               var newsData = await newsService.GetRandomNewsAsync();

               News.Clear();

               foreach (var newsdata in newsData)
                  News.Add(newsdata);

           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Debug.WriteLine(ex);
               await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Erreur", "Impossible", "Ok");
           }
           finally
           {
               IsBusy = false;
           }
```

```
[JsonPropertyName("source_id")]
       public string Id { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string Link { get; set; }
       public string Keywords { get; set; }
       public string Creator { get; set; }
       [JsonPropertyName("video_url")]
       public string VideoUrl { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
       public string Content { get; set; }
       public string PubDate { get; set; }
       [JsonPropertyName("full_description")]
       public string FullDescription { get; set; }
       [JsonPropertyName("image_url")]
       public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
       public string Country { get; set; }
       public string Category { get; set; }
       public string Language { get; set; }
```

```
 <RefreshView Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    Command="{Binding GetRandomNewsCommand}"
                    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}">
           <CollectionView x:Name="newsCollection"
                           BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                           SelectionMode="None">

               <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                   <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"/>
               </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

               <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:NewsDataModel">
                       <Grid Padding="5">
                           <Frame HeightRequest="125" Padding="0">
                               <Grid Padding="0" ColumnDefinitions="110, 160, *">
                                   
                                   <Image Aspect="AspectFit"
                                          Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                                          HeightRequest="96"
                                          WidthRequest="96"/>

                                   <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="1" Padding="10" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                       <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                                       <Label Text="{Binding Country}"/>
                                   </VerticalStackLayout>
                                   
                               </Grid>
                           </Frame>
                       </Grid>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
               
           </CollectionView>
       </RefreshView>
       
   </Grid>
```

Comment: `BASE_URL` is not a url, unless you didn't paste the real url.  What is the response code returned by your request?

Comment: according to the docs that you linked to, the url should be `https://newsdata.io/api/1/news?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY`

Comment: https://newsdata.io/api/1/news?apikey=/I put the key here/

Comment: then you should edit your post to reflect that, otherwise it appears that you're making an obvious mistake.  That said, what about my other questions?  What response are you actually getting back from the request?  Have you tried your url in a browser or Postman just to confirm that it works?

Comment: For Postman I just tested and it works. I didn't quite understand when you said you need to edit your post to reflect that. And as an answer when I put a BreakPoint to Busy it puts me = false.

Comment: put a breakpoint in `GetNewsAsync`  and step through it to see what it is doing and where it is going wrong

Comment: I have error messages in non public members, in response from GetNewsAsync

Comment: that doesn't tell me anything useful.  If you are getting an exception, what is the **specific** exception and what line is causing it?  Are you **sure** the json returned by the API can be mapped into a `NewsResult` class?  That would be the most likely thing to throw an exception in that method.

Comment: I confirm that I have no exception even when I launch the refresh

Comment: then what does "error messages in non public members" mean?  Does `newsData` contain data or not after that method executes?

Comment: When I hover my mouse over var newData = await Get News Async(response); (in GetNewsAsync) I am shown method, target and the non public members and when I click on it I receive error messages in: _InvocationBase, _InvocationList...

Comment: Please answer: Does `newsData` contain data or not after that method executes?

Comment: No he tells me that it null

Comment: Then something is not working in that method.  I can't debug it for you, you need to figure out what is going wrong.  I have already made several suggestions that you seem to be ignoring.  Check the response code.  Check the json.  Verify that the json can be deserialized into the `NewsResult` class

Comment: I didn't ignore but I told you I didn't understand

Comment: Don't understand what?  How to check the response code?  How to validate the json?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that I'm more of a beginner.

Comment: why are you using two completely different types here? `List<NewsDataModel> newsData` and `ReadFromJsonAsync<NewsResult>`

Comment: I separated into two parts: in the Result part there is public string status { get; set; }
         public int totalResults { get; set; }
         public List<NewsDataModel> Data { get; set; }

Comment: I just removed the page=10 and the answer was correct then I have an exception now: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: foreach (var newsdata in newsData)
                    News.Add(newsdata); (error for newsdata)

Comment: if you want to post the solution somewhere that I can download it I'll take a quick look.  But I can't spend all day walking you through how to debug this

Comment: I don't mind thank you, you can clone: https://github.com/JasonSile/Fictum.git

Comment: If possible, you may try changing the CollectionView to ListView. For more information, you may refer to the link:“ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70621034/how-do-i-send-and-display-get-requests-in-net-maui ”.

Answer (score 0):

this is your model

```
public class NewsResult
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int totalResults { get; set; }
    public List<NewsDataModel> Data { get; set; }
    public int nextPage { get; set; }
}
```

and this is your json

```
{"status":"success","totalResults":130061,"results": ...
```

note that the json does not have a property `Data`, but it does have a property `results`

either rename the property name in your model to match the json, or use a JSON mapping attribute

Comment: Can you please tell me how i owe the fame because i am trying to look and find how i should rename it as it shows me the same error, just to be sure

Comment: what?  The property name should literally be "results" to match the json